# List of wifi networks not shown, while wifi works

Tags: networking, network-manager

the wifi applet in the top-right of my screen shows no wifi networks (please see below), not even the one I am connected to. At the same time wifi, and in particular internet connection works. The list seems to be there after restart of a computer, but then vanishes at some point.
Is there a way to replenish the list?
I am uxing xubuntu 16.04.1.

[image]

**Edit:** by request, I attach output of *lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2*, while the problem was vanished by restart of the laptop.

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:10f5] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Dell 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection [1028:0233]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
--
0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:4235]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ultimate N WiFi Link 5300 [8086:1121]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep Net -A2`.

Comment: @JonasCz ok, byt it may take some time for the problem to reappear.

Comment: And it did not reappear...

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do a scan with `iw` in a shell, that would eventually help, "waking up" network manager :

```
sudo iw <interface> scan
```

Otherwise you do not need to restart the computer every time , just restart the network-manager service.

```
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

It should be enough to repopulate your scan list and get back to normality.